# Amazon Polly.Presigner Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js, amazon-polly

In an Angular app, I've setup an app that uses Amazon Polly to speak some unspeakable things based mainly on [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/javascript-browserstart-polly.html.html).

I've had to import Polly as such, because I can't get aws-sdk to allow importing AWS anymore, which used to work:

```
import { config, CognitoIdentityCredentials, Polly } from "aws-sdk";
```

I have imported @types/node, and I have added ["node'] under types, under compilerOptions in the tsconfig.app.json file.

And I have added the below to polyfills.ts:

```
(window as any).global = window;
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out why the 'polly' bit in the below is throwing an error that reads: **"Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2."**

It's preventing me from deploying a build.  What to do?!

```
speakText() {
    const polly = new Polly();
    // I don't know why 'polly' is bitching about expectations.
    const signer = new Polly.Presigner(this.speechParams, polly);
```

Comment: Is it an interpretation error or a linter error?

Comment: That's a good question!  The app compiles, so I believe it's a linter problem.  I've been trying to turn it off for a while now ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the docs that I reference to create this, might be incorrect when it comes to adding the speechParams and polly as options for the Polly.Presigner.

Removing these options removed the errors *and* the app still works as intended.

```
  speakText() {
    const polly = new Polly({ apiVersion: "2016-06-10" });
    const signer = new Polly.Presigner();  // <== Removed options!

    signer.getSynthesizeSpeechUrl(
      this.speechParams,
      700,
      (error: Error, url: string) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          this.audio.src = url;
          this.audio.load();
        }
      }
    );
  }
```